# Passing props between views in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to simply pass props between views in my React-Native app.  Namely, I am trying to collect data from a text input, and pass it to the next view in a string.  This is what I have:

first view:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: "", email: "" };
  }

  _pressRow(){
    let name=this.state.name;
    let email=this.state.email;

   this.props.navigator.push({
     ident: "ImportContactScreen",
     sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight,
     passProps: { name: name}
   });
  }

<TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            ref= "name"
            onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({name})}
            value={this.state.name}
          />

<F8Button
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => this._pressRow()}
            caption="Continue"
          />
```

second view:

```
props = {name}

<Text style={styles.h1}>Hi, {this.props.name}.  Let`'`s import your contacts:</Text>
```

The navigator I'm using looks like:

```
class MyAppNavigator extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        ref="appNavigator"
        initialRoute={this.props.initialRoute}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        configureScene={(route) => ({
          ...route.sceneConfig || Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight
        })}
      />
    );
  }

  _renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var globalNavigatorProps = { navigator }

    switch (route.ident) {
      case "LoginScreen":
        return <LoginScreen {...globalNavigatorProps} />
      case "UserFlowScreen":
        return <UserFlowScreen {...globalNavigatorProps} />
      case "ImportContactScreen":
        return <ImportContactScreen {...globalNavigatorProps} />
      default:
        return <LoginScreen {...globalNavigatorProps} />
    }
  }

};

module.exports = MyAppNavigator;
```

When I run this, this.props.name comes up blank

Comment: in your navigator screen add `{...route.passProps}` to all your screen like FuzzyTree mentioned in his answers. Then in your second view you can remove `props = {name}` you can just call your property like you already did `{this.props.name}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`passProps` is a property of `route`. Try adding `{...route.passProps}` to each return in your switch statement:

```
return <LoginScreen {...globalNavigatorProps} {...route.passProps} />
```